# Microsoft Analysis Services - Interact with Rails ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, ssas

I'm looking at leveraging an existing Microsoft SQL Server Analysis Service (`SSAS`) instance for a reporting project.  The goal is to have the data compiled in `SSAS`, then a web front-end that allows the user change time-periods, while building graphics (using `D3` or the like).

Google has not been my friend in finding a solution for this...

Is there a gem or other way to connect SSAS to a Rails front-end?

Thanks

Comment: You didn't elaborate why do you want to use Rails? I'm asking because it would be much more easier to find methods to access SSAS from Microsoft's stack (namely .NET and/or ASP.NET + ADO).

Comment: Wanting to use Rails because a divergence in technology in my company.  Our business intelligence backend is Microsoft SQL Server, all the front-end is non-Microsoft.  The front-end team can build the interface if the data can get served to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON, no, not that I know of.  However if you are willing to use XML, then yes.  XMLA (documented [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186604.aspx)) is the client API language for SSAS.

Comment: Thanks.  I think if you can pull the data into a the model in rails, then rails can return JSON.  You bring up a good point about the XML versus JSON.  I need to edit the question - More focused on getting the data into Rails, then letting the front-end render the output.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to build a web service with .NET, and then have your Rails front-end call the web service.

I suppose you could use XMLA directly, but it's painful.